# How to dynamically add an object in schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like this-

```
var schema= new mongoose.Schema({
  username:{type:String},
  responses:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed}
});
```

I save a document in the collection it is like-

```
{ username:anonymous,responses:{}}
```

Now I want this to update to -

```
{username:anonymous,responses:{tst123:{duration:30,res:{}},tet456:{duration:50,res:{}}}
```

I want to update the document in the following step as it goes-

1) `responses:{}`

2) `responses:{test123:{},res:{}}`

3) `responses:{test123:{dur:30,refresh:false},res:{{key1:val1}} }`

4) `responses:{ test123:{dur:30,refresh:false},res {{key1:val1},key2:val2} }`

Similarly, I want to add `test456` and even more tests, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in the **[update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)** method as follows:

```
var schema= new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String },
    responses: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }
});

var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', schema),
    query = { 'username': 'anonymous' },
    update = { 
        '$set': { 
            'responses': {
                'tst123': {
                    'duration': 30,
                    'res': {}
                },
                'tet456': {
                    'duration': 50,
                    'res': {}
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    options = { multi: true };

Thing.update(query, update, options, callback);

function callback (err, numAffected) {
  // numAffected is the number of updated documents
})
```

Comment: I want to dynamically add objects in responses field and res field it may be more than two. How to do it in generalized way ?

Comment: @NitishKumar Can you edit your question and include some examples? You mentioned how you want the responses key should be updated and I provided that in the above. If you need to dynamically create the update object then you can set the object by using the [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: I want to update the document in the following step as it goes-                         1) responses:{} 2)responses:{test123:{},res:{}}                                             3) responses:{test123:{dur:30,refresh:false},res:{{key1:val1}} }                                     4) responses:{ test123:{dur:30,refresh:false},res {{key1:val1},key2:val2} }        simillarly I want to add test456 and even more tests